# For loop breaks when it encounters an image that doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to load a series of images inside a div using for loop and when the file does not exist, the `for` loop breaks. This code doesn't seem to work.

I've tested many others but no success. Any tips?

HTML:

```
<div id="project_img">
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function load_projects()
  var project_array = new Array();
  var project_name;

  for(var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    project_array.push(new Image());

    project_name = "project_" + i;

    project_array[i].src = "images/" + project_name + ".png";
    project_array[i].id = project_name;

    $("#project_img").append(project_array[i]);

    $("#" + project_name).error(function() {
      alert(i);
      i = 7;
    })
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  load_projects();
});
```

Comment: I assume the missing `{` after `function load_projects()` is just a typo? Otherwise I don't see what's broken, the for loop works and I get a bunch of invalid images: http://jsfiddle.net/fEQgJ/

Comment: hey thanks for the reply, yea the for loop works 
but I am trying to the stop the for loop as soon as 
an image does not exist, that's why I change i=7 
but the loop won't stop, it still loads the invalid images : s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that the error-callbacks will be called after the `for` loop has finished (runs from 0 till 7).

If you want to start loading next image if there is no error loading the current image, you have to change your strategy: you need a success callback, which starts loading the next one. jQuerys [load](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) method can be used to set a callback if an image has been successfully loaded:

```
$("...").load(function() { ... });
```

If current image has been loaded and not all images has been displayed, start loading next one:

```
$("#" + project_name).load(function() {
    if (i < 7) {
        load_projects(i + 1);
    }
});
```

So the `for` loop isn't needed anymore. The complete code is:

```
var project_array = new Array();

function load_projects(i) {
    project_array.push(new Image());
    project_array[i].id = "project_" + i;
    project_array[i].src = "images/" + project_array[i].id + ".png";

    $("#project_img").append(project_array[i]);

    $("#" + project_array[i].id).load(function() {
        if (i < 7) {
            load_projects(i + 1);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    load_projects(0);
});
```

Not neccessary but if you want you can add the error callback again:

```
    ...
    $("#" + project_array[i].id).error(function() {
        alert('error at ' + i);
    });
    ...
```

Also see my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vmKxw/1/). (There I have added one existing image.)

Comment: thanks ! it's really detailed, why is the error callbacks will only run after for loop is done, isn't it nested inside the for loop ??

Comment: The jQuery error method adds only a callback and continues. The events will be triggered from outside the function and calls the callback only when the error was discovered. (Then the for loop has already been finished.)

Comment: thanks I think I got it =) 
just checked the error() description again and it explains, 'The error event is sent to elements, such as images, that are referenced by a document and loaded by the browser'

Comment: btw do you know about onerror, is the event referenced to document as well ??

Comment: Both are the same event. Without using jQuery you can use the `onerror` attribute to catch the `error-event`, with jQuery you can use the `error` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function drawImage(i) {

project_array.push(new Image());

var project_name = "project_" + i;

project_array[i].src = "images/" + project_name + ".png";
project_array[i].id = project_name;

$("#project_img").append(project_array[i]);

$("#" + project_name).load(function() {
   if ( i + 1 < 7)
     drawImage(i + 1);  
}) ;  
 }

$(document).ready(function() {
  drawImage(0);
});

var project_array = new Array();
```